# How to add a new LDAP'ed user to subversion

Tags: linux, svn, ldap, collabnet

Our SVN administrator is on holidays, and I need to add a new user to subversion.

We're using Collabnet Subversion on a RedHat box.

I've found the **CollabNet_Subversion/conf/** directory with all the configuration files, including an auth file that I can see contains all our users and the groups that they belong to.

All our users need to log in with their LDAP credentials, so I don't need to change any of that.

It looks something like this:
company_auth_production

```
   `[groups]
    it-leads = jsmith, hsimpson, pgriffin
    it-all = ajolie, rwitherspoon, @it-leads

    [/]
    * =

    [prod:/]
    @it-all = rw
    `
```

So I added the new user and restarted subversion.  But that doesn't seem to have done the trick.  Am I missing something else ?  Thanks

Comment: Did you add the new user information to both the application configuration and the LDAP server database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a. You have mention that there is "company_auth_production" file. Please check if there is some other authorization file, probably "authz". Can you please provide more information on this.

As per the structure in your file

[prod:/]
@it-all = rw

should have given the read write access to all the users of "it-all" till the path "prod".

b. If this is not working then please try using "VisualSVN Server". It has a very nice gui to add users and give them priviledges also.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your apache Configuration is usually a **require** directive (eg "require group" or "require user"). Often there is a specific group which user has to belong to access svn (eg svnusers, etc...)